# How to parse json request in java spark

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to parse JSON object that is sent using HTTP post "body" request in java-spark. For example if I send JSON object like :

> {\"name"\ : \"john\", \"age\":\"300\"}

.
I want to get the name and age in different strings. I have tried this so far in java-spark :

```
post("/test", "application/json", (req,res) -> {
 String name = req.queryParams("name");
 return "hi : " +  name;
});
```

but it returns hi : null as result.

I searched a lot on the internet but I keep finding complicated results, is there a simple way?
Note : This is not Apache spark.

EDIT : I have managed to add JSON-simple lib as a dependency in pom.xml, and I tried the following :

```
JSONObject obj = new  JSONObject(req.body());
```

But I get an error :

> String cannot be converted to map

Although that line works in my android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please validate whether the string you are getting is in proper JSON format or not. And to validate that you can use [Validate JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Once it is validated you can try following thing.

I beleive instead of JSONObject you should have used its parse to parse JSON.

For example :

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
String s = "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
```

Try below links which I hope will help you to understand better.

[JSON Parser1](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/)

[JSON Parser2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed!